# FutureBuilder<?> flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to fetch data from an API when a FAB gets clicked.

I have read the documentation (https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data) related to that though have problems with the FutureBuilder's type.

The same way can define a `Future<Event>` cannot do the same for the `FutureBuilder<Event>`.

```dart
import 'exports.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Event {
  Event({
    required this.name,
    required this.desc,
    required this.eventDate,
    required this.pic,
    required this.price,
    required this.events,
  });

  String name;
  String desc;
  String eventDate;
  String pic;
  int price;
  List<String> events;

  factory Event.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Event(
    name: json["name"],
    desc: json["desc"],
    eventDate: json["eventDate"],
    pic: json["pic"],
    price: json["price"],
    events: List<String>.from(json["events"].map((x) => x)),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "title": name,
    "description": desc,
    "eventDate": eventDate,
    "pic": pic,
    "price": price,
    "images": List<dynamic>.from(events.map((x) => x)),
  };
}

Future<Event> fetchEvents() async {

  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('localhost:3007/events'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If server returns a 200 > response OK > parse the JSON
    return Event.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  }

  else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load events');
  }

}

class EventList extends StatefulWidget {
  const EventList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  State<EventList> createState() => _EventListState();
}

class _EventListState extends State<EventList> {

  String eventsAPI = 'localhost:3007/events';

  late Future<Event> futureEvent;

  void initState() {
     super.initState();
     futureEvent = fetchEvents();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,

    home: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.green[500],

      appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: const Text('Listado Eventos', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40)),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green[900],
        ),

      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                heroTag: 'GET',
                backgroundColor: Colors.green[900],
                onPressed: null,
                child: const Text('GET', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),

              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                heroTag: 'BACK',
                backgroundColor: Colors.green[900],
                onPressed: backHome,
                child: const Text('BACK', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )

    ),

  );

  void backHome() {
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'backHome');
  }

  // error
  FutureBuilder<Eve>

}
```

Wonder if anyone could help?

Comment: What's that FutureBuilder doing there? Of course it gives an error like that. It needs to be part of your Widget structure inside your build method. Also you are writing FutureBuilder<Eve> instead of FutureBuilder<Event>. You can use FutureBuilder<Event> just fine

Comment: @Ivo use it outside my build method was the prob, thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

First off, what are you trying to do with the data? Build UI? Logic with data?

Below is how you should use a FutureBuilder to build UI off of a future function.

```
FutureBuilder(
 future: http.get(Uri.parse('localhost:3007/events')),
 builder: (context, snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.hasData){
   return Widget()
  }
  return CircularProgressIndicator()
 },
)
```

Comment: `future: http.get(Uri.parse('localhost:3007/events')),` {sigh} Don't build the future as the future: parameter in FutureBuilder. See the first few paragraphs of the FutureBuilder documentation, or see my video at https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg

Comment: I was just showing that to go with his example, not going to include a service function just to define as a future in an answer {sigh}

Comment: The problem is that people don't know the shortcuts you took for an answer, and will copy your code literally, and then be posting their own SO question because it doesn't work "sometimes".  This is why I adamantly seek these out to correct them.